# DomPDF runs very slow in Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I am generating a document with Blade and DomPDF in Laravel, my code works fine and I have tried to optimize it all. But it keeps generating the documents too slow. On the controller side, I just make two queries to the database and send a JSON ($data) to the blade view to render.

The code to generate my PDF document is as follows:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('oficio', $data);
pdf->getDomPDF()->set_option("enable_php", true);
pdf->setPaper('letter');
pdf->render();
$pdf->stream();
```

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Try to remove unnecessary things from the HTML. Reduce the number of images in the document to only two (one in the header and one in the footer).

I expect the document to take less than 5 seconds to generate, currently it takes about 10 seconds, which is too slow for such a small document.